# nested structures in C

Tags: c, structure

goal: ask user for the number of agencies, create said agencies, and for each agency ask for the number of employees, and create those employees.

part of this will require, I think, nested structure, something like

```
typedef struct agence agence;
struct agence
{
    char nom[20];
    int nmbrEmp;
    struct employe
    {
        char mat[20];
        int nmbrEnf;
        int ANC;
        double SB;
        double RCNSS;
    }
};
```

is this n the right path, and how do you proceed to create the number of agencies/employees once the users gives you the number required of each.

Comment: Have you used `malloc` before?

Comment: Allocate memory for your structure and store the inputted value

Answer (score 0):

C unlike C++ cannot have nested types, you will have to declare them separately.

```
struct employe
{
    char mat[20];
    int nmbrEnf;
    int ANC;
    double SB;
    double RCNSS;
};

struct agence
{
    char nom[20];
    int nmbrEmp;
    struct employe * employees; // pointer to an array of employees
};
```

Then use dynamic memory and populate them:

```
struct agence * agencies;
size_t num_agencies = 100;

agencies = calloc(sizeof(*agencies), num_agencies);

for (/* read egancies somehow */) {
    agencies[i].nmbrEmp = number_employees;
    agencies[i].employees = calloc(sizeof(agencies[i].employees[0]), number_employees);

    // write agencies[i].employees[j] ...
}
```

Comment: Nested structures: OK. Nested types (the way he tried to define em): not OK. The OP wants to save a number of employees per agency though, so he needs either a pointer to employee or a VLA.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this Example :

```
struct Employee
{
   char ename[20];
   int ssn;
   float salary;
   struct date
       {
       int date;
       int month;
       int year; 
       }doj;
}emp1;

Accessing Nested Members :

Accessing Month Field :  emp1.doj.month   
Accessing day Field   :  emp1.doj.day  
Accessing year Field  :  emp1.doj.year
```

Here is the Code pad which will demonstrate the above example

[enter link description here](http://codepad.org/4T4Je9i1)

Answer (score 0):

In c, you cannot have unnamed nested structures [otherwise, nested types]. They have to be a named structure. You need to write something like

```
typedef struct agency
{
    char nom[20];
    int nmbrEmp;
    struct employee
    {
        char mat[20];
        int nmbrEnf;
        int ANC;
        double SB;
        double RCNSS;
    } emp [20];
}agency;
```

However, here you are limited to the static input of a size `20`, that means, you cannot have more than 20 employee records. To liberate from this limitation , the best approach is to use a pointer to an `employee` structure, an in runtime, allocate memory based on the number of the employee given by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example you might consider. This is a template of what you have to do, you are left with manipulating employees, agencies name and so on. (Note that there's no error checking, which is bad.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* TODO: modify members */
typedef struct {
    int id;
    int salary;
} employee;

/* TODO: modify members */
typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    employee* emps;
    int emps_count;
} agency;

/* return sum of id and salary for first employee from agency */
int dumb_calc(agency ag) {
    return ag.emps[0].id + ag.emps[0].salary;
}

int main(void)
{
    int num_ag;
    int num_emps;
    int i, j;
    printf("enter num of agencies:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num_ag);
    agency* agencies = malloc(sizeof(agency) * num_ag);

    for (i = 0; i < num_ag; ++i) {
        /* TODO: modify single agency name */
        sprintf(agencies[i].name, "agency %d", i+1);
        printf("enter num of employees for agency %d\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &num_emps);
        agencies[i].emps = malloc(sizeof(employee) * num_emps);
        agencies[i].emps_count = num_emps;
        for (j = 0; j < num_emps; ++j) {
            /* TODO: modify single employee */
            agencies[i].emps[j].id = j+1;
            agencies[i].emps[j].salary = 1000*(j+1);
        }
    }

    /* TODO: change printing style */
    for (i = 0; i < num_ag; ++i) {
        printf("agency name: %s\n", agencies[i].name);
        printf("num of employees: %d\n", agencies[i].emps_count);
        /* result will always be the same */
        printf("sum of id and salary for 1st emp: %d\n", dumb_calc(agencies[i]));
    }

    /* remember to free what you've alloc'd */
    for (i = 0; i < num_ag; ++i) {
        free(agencies[i].emps);
    }
    free(agencies);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can pass them to function as two int values or take `agency` as an function argument, access members within function, calculate and return result. I've edited answer to show you some way of doing it.